# Meteor setPersistent for CSS styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, meteor

I have this method, which changes the opacity of the object clicked to 0.4

```
'click .detailCheckbox': function(ev){
    var detail = $(ev.target).parent();

    Session.setPersistent('class', 'toggle');
    detail.addClass(Session.get('class'));
}
```

On a page reload, the `class` key still has a value of `toggle`, but the DOM element is no longer styled with the class I have in my CSS called `toggle`, which has opacity 0.4.

How do I persist this style change?

Comment: Either use cookies or post back.

Comment: using [cookies + Sessions](http://meteorpad.com/pad/j7Fea3kEQpzZ65qCG/Leaderboard)

Comment: It looks like you're doing it correctly. Do you have any errors in your js console? Also if you check your `localStorage` does it have the items in after you click the button? Do you set `class` anywhere else in your code, including defaults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a new field in the model, which is set (or unset) to the class name that has opacity 0.4

Here is the Meteor method insert method that contains the field `checkboxStatus`

```
addDetail: function(detailFormData){
    if(! Meteor.userId()){
        throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
    }

    detailsCollection.insert({
        detail: detailFormData.detail,
        parentId: detailFormData.parentId,
        checkboxStatus: detailFormData.checkboxStatus  
    });
}
```

I call it on the clicking of the checkbox:

```
'click .detailCheckbox': function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();

    Meteor.call('setToggle', this._id);
}
```

And the `setToggle` Meteor method checks the toggle status, and then updates the document accordingly

```
setToggle: function(detailId){
    var checked_detail = detailsCollection.findOne({_id: detailId});

    if(checked_detail.checkboxStatus != 'toggle'){
        detailsCollection.update(detailId, {
            $set: {checkboxStatus: 'toggle'}
        });
    } else {
        detailsCollection.update(detailId, {
            $set: {checkboxStatus: 'untoggle'}
        });
    }

}
```

Which is then called by a template helper method

```
checkboxStatus: function(){
    var checked_detail = detailsCollection.findOne({_id: this._id});
    return checked_detail.checkboxStatus;
}
```

whose value is returned in the class tag of the template item itself

`<li id={{_id}} class="detailViewEntry {{checkboxStatus}}">`